# How to fail a Control M job when running a python function

Tags: python, shell, control-m

I have a Control-M job that calls a python script. The python script contains a function that returns True or False.

Is it possible to make the job to fail when the function returns False?

I have to use a shell scrip for this? If yes how should i create it?

Thank you

Comment: Returning a non-zero value should work, i.e. `sys.exit(1)` if the function returns `False`, `sys.exit(0)` otherwise.

Comment: Hi, yes. This i how i've done and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return a non-zero value -- i.e. call `sys.exit(1)` when function returns `False`, and `sys.exit(0)` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, quicker GUI implementation (without having to change the code at all) in the "Actions" tab, you can add an "on-do"

```
On specific statement output: 
Statement: *
Code: *False*
Do: Set to NOT OK
```

Just keep in mind if you do change your python code, you'd have to change this job as well.